# Can tags do some calculations in a RFID system?

Tags: tags, rfid

Can tags and readers do some calculations in a RFID system? I found many papers designed security protocols to enhance the security of RFID systems. In those protocols, tags and readers are required to do necessary calculations, such as exclusive OR (XOR), random number generation, and even hash operation and so on. 
However, to my understanding, tags and readers do not have the calculation ability, then how to implement these protocols? We need design special tags and readers? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like nfc capable smartcards, not just plain tags

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, we need low cost passive tags in our system that are programmable and EPC Class-1 Gen 2 compliant, you mean we can use the nfc capable smartcard instead?

Comment: http://www.library.ca.gov/crb/rfidap/docs/SCA-EPC_Gen_2_FAQ_FINAL.pdf

Comment: I have read the reference. It seems that the contactless smartcard is not the one we are looking for. A tag programmable and EPC Class-1 Gen 2 compliant is required. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This heavily depends on the type of RFID system (frequency, communication standard, etc) and the type of tag (passive or active/semi-passive).

For instance, with UHF backscatter systems, passive tags usually contain only a small memory (and logic to process commands).

In the HF range, there is ISO/IEC 14443. For that standard, there exist lots of passive tags (contactless smartcards) that contain a processing unit and can even execute complex program code. ISO/IEC 15693 (same frequency range, different standard) passive tags usually conain only memory and some additional control logic (e.g. password-based locking/unlocking). The same applies to tags in the LF range.

Active tags (regardless of the standard, as long as the standard contains some form of command response protocol if you want to interact with that functionality), however could do pretty much any calculation if they contain an appropriate processing unit.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael Roland! In our system, we need to use low cost passive tags that are programmable and EPC Class-1 Gen 2 compliant. Do you know if there is this kind of tags? And could please recommend some types? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia (I read the German version) one can build complex microchips into any RFID. It's also possible to add Sensor as for example  GPS. RFID chips do not need to be passive, they can have a battery to power the whole RFID chip (active) or just the microprocessor (semi passive).